# good period prediction but bad magnitude using keras LSTM neural network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, tensor

I want to predict the voltage of a battery along time using neural networks. This voltage is read using an ADC and generates a charge/discharge profile that ideally looks like this:

[image]

Which goes very similar along time (up to hundreds of cycles) but with a different period each cycle (even each charge/discharge part), depending on if the battery is being charged or discharged (one cycle is one charge + one discharge). Tch stands for charge period and Tdc for discharge period. I want to predict this voltage in future cycles. Specifically, my main objective is to predict with accuracy the period of each cycle, to know if this period increases or decreases.

I already have a data set with 1 million samples (one sample is the voltage value each 2 seconds), which I used to train and predict an LSTM using keras. The results are pretty good: for the train part of the set,  RMSE = 0.01; and for the test part, it is 0.01 The following figure shows the actuals vs predictions for some of the cycles, where both period and magnitude matches almost perfectly:

[image]

My problem comes when I try to predict on a new smaller dataframe (around 4000 samples): the period is predicted perfectly but the magnitude it is not (blue is actuals and green is prediction). For example, the maxmvoltage values are larger in the prediction than in the actuals (more than 5V vs no more than 1.7V). I have plotted it in different axes to see better the differences:

[image]

Is there anyway to improve the magnitude prediction but maintaining the nice quality of the period prediction?